# How to share settings with Run cunfigurations (like inheritance)

Tags: intellij-idea

I have configurated about 100 different Run configurations in my node project. recently was introduced into the project some environment variables

How to share the same info between all run configurations without edit one by one

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to perform such an operation in the IntelliJ IDEA UI. However, the run configurations are stored as .xml files under the .idea directory in your project root. You can run a batch operation on these files to make the changes you need.